# "Touching" duplicates of the same sprite. Swift/Spritekit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

What I'm trying to accomplish is to spawn in a sprite on the screen that can be touched and dragged, and on a one second timer I want a duplicate of this sprite to be spawned.

What I have now is the sprites spawning in as they should, but only the first one is able to be touched, and the others are "immune" to the touch.

Do I have to do something like assign a different variable name to the sprite and cycle through spawning it in with a different name, or is there a way to just apply my touches func to every copy of the sprite?

Comment: Could you share what you have so far? It might help.

Comment: Are you using a local or global instance of the sprite you want to move? Posting your relevant code may help.